# Is there a way to set "permissions" on PulseAudio controls?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

I'm on a multiseat system where PulseAudio is set up as system-wide daemon using systemd. Works perfectly fine, but a user now needs access to the PA server (audio-depending app.).

Is there a way I can allow a user access to the PA server for audio playback and recording without allowing the user full access to PA? E.g. I don't want the user to change sink/source settings or volumes for other streams.

Ideally I'm looking for something that would allow a certain user "readonly" access to Pulse. The app. has volume controls built-in, so no volume control on Pulse would be needed for the user at all.

What should also work is if there is a way I can define some sink/source/volume routings/levels in a config file and make that somehow persistent, so it can't be changed by a non-root user.

The system is Debian 9 using XFCE4 as desktop.

Comment: Use tcp module as `load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.0/24`, then your clients can connect to localhost.

Comment: @IporSircer I've tried similar, but using the UNIX socket module instead of the TCP one. In that case, the user accessing PA through the socket has full control and can mute/control audio streams started by root too, which is not what I desire. I assume TCP would act the same as UNIX, or am I wrong here?

Comment: Then modify the source.

Comment: You can control access to pulseaudio with SELinux. https://linux.die.net/man/8/pulseaudio_selinux